# jqGrid how handle event enter key after edit column thanks to editRow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am starting to use the jQuery plug in jqGrid  for rendering nice tables, I want to make just one column editable.

I manage to render a table where a textbox come up when i click on my editable column, nevertheless I don't manage to catch when a cell has been edited (after enter has been pressed) . When I read doc, I suppose I have to use *`aftersavefunc`* but I don't know where and how it has to be used.

Could you help me please?

Bellow my exemple I would like to complete.

```js
 var mydata = [{
            name: "Toronto",
            country: "Canada",
            continent: "North America"
        }, {
            name: "New York City",
            country: "USA",
            continent: "North America"
        }, {
            name: "Silicon Valley",
            country: "USA",
            continent: "North America"
        }, {
            name: "Paris",
            country: "France",
            continent: "Europe"
        }]
        
        function edit(id) {
                var table = jQuery(this);
                table.jqGrid('editRow', id,
        {
            keys: true,  
        });
        }
    
    
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        data: mydata,
        datatype: "local",
        colNames: ["Name", "Country", "Continent"],
        colModel: [{
            name: 'name',
            index: 'name'  
        }, {
            name: 'country',
            index: 'country',
            editable: true,
        }, {
            name: 'continent',
            index: 'continent'    
        }],
        onSelectRow: edit
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.js"></script>
<table id="grid"></table>
```

Comment: Which version of jqGrid and from which fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use? The possibilities to place the options are different in different forks of jqGrid. I develop free jqGrid fork and can explain you its possibility. At the beginning I'd recommend you to use unique `id` property in every input item. It's especially important in case of usage editing.

Comment: What kind of actions you need to do inside of `aftersavefunc`? Where the data come from and where you want to save the results of editing? Do you have `<input>` element in the `country` column during editing or for example select with the predefined list of countries?

Comment: @Oleg thank  you for your help . the data come from a server but is enter as static data (I am on an old project) . The version : "4.6.0", is used. During editing I have an input text. In aftersavefunc I would like to send in POST the new value to my server

Comment: The simplest way (but not always the best) to set `aftersavefunc` together with `keys: true`: `keys: true, aftersavefunc: function (rowid) { alert(rowid + " is saved"); }`. To send the data to the server you can use `editurl` parameter of jqGrid or `url` parameter of `editRow`. The version 4.6 is really old. I'd recommend you better to use free jqGrid 4.13.0 (my fork) or Guriddo jqGrid JS 5.0.2 (commercial edition).

Comment: it is working , thank you very much, you should post it as answere.

Comment: unfortunately I am not enough influental for changing plug in version but now I know my version you helped me for my future searches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `aftersavefunc` for example together with other options of `editRow`:

```
table.jqGrid('editRow', id, {
    keys: true,
    url: "myServerUrl", // it's optional
    aftersavefunc: function (rowid) { // can add jqXHR, sentData, options 
        alert(rowid + " is saved");
    }
});
```

The next problem: **I would strictly recommend you to add `id` property in the input data** used for filling the grid. The `id` property will be saved as the value of `id` attribute of every row (`<tr>`) element, used in callbacks and will be send to the server on editing. I'd recommend you to remove all `index` properties from jqGrid too and add the option `autoencode: true` to jqGrid. If you use old 4.6 version then you should add `gridview: true` option to improve the performance of the grid and to add `height: "auto"` option too.

The next problem: it's recommended to save/discard previously edited row inside of `onSelectRow`. You need call `saveRow` or `restoreRow`. You current code can produces many **simultaneously edited rows**. The user can forget to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and thought that the rows are already modified. I'd recommend you to add at least navigator bar  with edit/save/cancel buttons by `inlineNav` *additionally* to your current code. It helps some users to save the rows.

One more remark. jqGrid 4.6 is already old. There are currently two main forks of jqGrid: [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) in the current version 4.13.0 and commercial version [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). Both versions contains many new features, but there will be more and more different. I develop free jqGrid after [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438) about renaming jqGrid to Guriddo jqGrid JS and changing the license agreement. I provided free jqGrid under the same licenses (MIT and GPLv2) like old versions of jqGrid (4.6 for example). You can use it from CDNs too (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). jqGrid 4.6 is dead. No bug fix or new feature will be developed. You wrote that you are starting to use jqGrid. In the case it's especially bad to use some old version.